# Corona SDK Facebook api showDialog properties do not work

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, lua, coronasdk

I'm about to submit my latest app/game, and it seems something changed, since my call to Facebook's showDialog only works half way.
This is the structure I'm using to make the call which worked fine a month ago when I last tested it:

```
local fb_publish_properties = {};
    fb_publish_properties["iTunes"] = {};
    fb_publish_properties["iTunes"]["text"] = "Blabla text to be shown";
    fb_publish_properties["iTunes"]["href"] = "https://The link to open on text click";
    fb_publish_properties["GooglePlay"] = {};
    fb_publish_properties["GooglePlay"]["text"] = "Blabla text to be shown";
    fb_publish_properties["GooglePlay"]["href"] = "https://The link to open on text click";
    local fb_publish_properties2 = json.encode(fb_publish_properties);

    local fb_publish_params = {
        app_id = facebook_appId,
        from = user_fb_id,
        to = user_fb_id,
        picture = "http://icon picture here",
        name = "Title of post",
        caption = "Come play against me!!",
        description = "",
        properties = fb_publish_properties2;
    }
    facebook.showDialog("feed",fb_publish_params);
```

Now, as I said, this worked just fine a month ago, but now, it posts the post to the feed alright, but nothing of the properties is shown in the post, and while clicking on the post itself, it leads to the message icon (which I believe happens since he doesn't recognized any other links in the message).

First, what is wrong with Facebook, changing their API every 2 months!!?? but now really, what is wrong with the piece of code which used to work but now works only partly?

Thanks all!

UPDATE:
After not doing anything about it, just going on as normal, some of the things started working on their own, for example, now when the Facebook API opens on the device (iOs or Android) I see the texts just fine as they are supposed to be, yet when I publish to stream, the post that shows online again, shows only the caption text, not the properties texts and links, and when I click on my post online, it leads to the icon file I'm using and not to the links I've published.

This is the last thing that stops me from publishing this app, please, someone, help??!

Comment: Have you checked whether their API docs related to your code shows there might have been changes? If you are 100% sure that they did not change anything, then most likely your memory is wrong, or you changed something inadvertently (like pressed a key in editor without noticing and saved, depending on where this may not cause crash but only wrong logic).

Comment: I've checked, nothing changes, at least not in the documents, which doesn't mean they didn't change anything, you can still find documents of stuff they stopped supporting years ago and still did not update, they are great at updating, but terrible at updating their documents. I hate Facebook so much, I do.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, but does not fit in a comment:

Try the following to see if you get anything at all:

```
facebook.showDialog( "feed", {link="http://www.coronasdk.com/"} ) 
facebook.showDialog( "apprequests", {message="some message"} )
```

Please update your post accordingly, describing what you observe, then I can then erase this. Also ensure that login succeeded (the fbconnect event properties of didComplete, isError and expiration).